# React reloads the page after replacing images

Tags: node.js, reactjs

I am uploading images to a server. If it is present and replaced, then React refreshes the page with a loss of state. How can I stop this behavior?

Node:

```
let form = new formidable.IncomingForm();
form.parse(req, function (err, fields, files) {
    let {size, path, name, type} = files.image,
        newpath = pathLib.join(__dirname, '../client/public/uploads') + name;
    fs.rename(path, newpath, function (err) {
        if(err) throw err;
    });
});
```

React:

```
<form id="uploadForm">
    <input id="uploadInput" name="image" type="file" />
</form>
<span onClick={() => {
    let form = document.querySelector("#uploadForm"),
        formData = new FormData(form);
    if(form.querySelector("#uploadInput").files.length)
        uploadFiles(formData, (res) => { 
            console.log(res.data.errors);
        }); 
}}>Save</span>
```

**An important addition!** Page refreshed even without interaction with React components. Replacing an image through the Windows file manager calls the re-render.

Comment: By posting your code here first.

Comment: The code doesn't really matter. I conducted an experiment and did the following: I copied and pasted the file with the replacement not using React and the browser, but using the Windows file manager. The effect is the same.

Comment: And how would you think people here solve the problem? Post the client code. You might be missing `e.preventDefault()` in your form submission.

Answer (score 0):

Just call event.preventDefault() when submit form. See the example here:

```
<form  id="formSubmit"}>
    <input id="uploadInput" name="image" type="file" />
   <button type="submit"></button>
</form>

document.getElementById('formSubmit').addEventListener('submit',function(event){
  event.preventDefault()
  // write here your others code
})
```

Comment: I tried your version. Added a submit button and submit event along with the code "event.preventDefault ()". This did not stop the page reloading when the file was overwritten. This solution prevents the submit from being reloaded, my original way does not trigger the form submission.

Comment: You can try another way to stop page reload. like the example here : <form action="#" onsubmit="yourJsFunction();return false">
    <input type="text"/>
    <input type="submit"/>
</form>